# How to fix: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've checked a lot of articles on internet and tried to apply suggestions, but nothing is working.

My configuration looks as following:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "js_class",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^5.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin()
]
};
```

The error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- D:\Programiranje\Code\js\js_class\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programiranje\Code\js\js_class\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\Programiranje\\Code\\js\\js_class\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest switching to the `webpack serve` command rather than using `webpack-dev-server` directly: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759#issuecomment-706673994.

Comment: It didn't help, but thank you anyway. The installation of webpack-cli 3.3.12 helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation of webpack-cli 3.3.12 helped to solve the issue.